# Add Gerrit custom label with defaultValue +1

Tags: gerrit

Commit to my project is triggering external Jenkins Pipeline that does plenty of checks and a release after submit. All projects have a custom label `No-Release` known by the pipline (set to 0 from default) and submitting with no release needs additional action - checking the checkbox.
What I want to do is to disable release by default on this project. How to set defaultValue of a custom label to +1?

Label from my config (this label appears as a checkbox, not radio):

```
[label "No-Release"]
    function = NoBlock
    value =  0 Enable release of jar
    value = +1 Skip release of jar
    defaultValue = +1
```

With above configuration the label does not have any value after commit and I still have to manually click the checkbox and post it.
In projects that have set `defaultValue = 0` there is also no info appearing after commit.

Does it mean that the `defaultValue` is being read somehow during submit and the default +1 will be taken by Gerrit but it just doesn't mark the label on review? If so, what to do if I exceptionally want to release, since the checkbox doesn't appear checked?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your question.

First of all, remember that a label created with "function = NoBlock" is purely informational and its value isn't considered when determining whether a change is submittable or not.

The "defaultValue" is not used automatically after the push to Gerrit, when a default value is defined, that value will just get set in the Reply dialog by default.

See more info about Gerrit labels [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-labels.html#label_custom).

Comment: Hi, I know that NoBlock doesn't influence a submit and that is good because my label can be set to 0 and submit should be available.
I checked the info in attached documentation but I didn't find the answer.
If defaultValue will get set in the Reply dialog, that means I still have something wrong, because it is set to 0 after push (checkbox unchecked).

Comment: I didn't understand your doubt. The label WON'T be set to the default value (+1) after the push. This is how it's supposed to work and, I think, this is what is happening, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is happening.The label is not set. However, if the default value can point to the value in Reply dialog only, is it possible ONLY for defaultValue=0 ?